# submit multiple rows at a time mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rows

i have a php generated form:

```
 <form action='step2.php' method="post" name='frm<? echo $socialid; ?>' id="frm_step2">
       <?
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM socials WHERE network not in (SELECT network FROM networks WHERE user='$_SESSION[user_id]') ");

while($socialrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $socialid=$socialrow['id'];
    $socialnet=$socialrow['network'];
    ?>
   <a href="#" class="edit_<? echo $socialnet;?>"><img src="smallicons/<? echo $socialnet;?>.png" width="30" alt="<? echo $socialnet;?>" /></a>
    <div class="table_<? echo $socialnet;?>">the full url to your <? echo $socialnet;?> profile:<br />
    <input type='hidden' value='<? echo $socialnet;?>' name='network'/>
     <input type='text' name='urltonet'/> <br/>
    </div>

<?
}
    ?>
  <br />  <input type='submit' value='enter' />
  </form>
```

basicly for every social network in the database it creates a form where the user needs to fill in their url to their profile
so if the user still has to fill in 2 network urls, it will show two forms , one for each with one submit button

so if the user fills in both text boxes it will need to insert these values in the same database

any idea or help on how to insert these values please?
below my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `networks` (
`user` int(30) NOT NULL,
`network` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL default 'not known',
`url` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`user_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`netid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
PRIMARY KEY (`netid`),
UNIQUE KEY `netid` (`netid`),
UNIQUE KEY `netid_2` (`netid`),
UNIQUE KEY `netid_3` (`netid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=239 ;
```

Comment: why netid is primary..is this network table primary key

Comment: @gowri yes , this needs to be unique as i dont want people adding 2 the same networks. i am not sure if this is actually needed as primary but so far this code works perfect

Answer (score 0):

as far as syntax goes it's you can use this, somehow i have feeling that is not what you wnat to know

```
insert into networks (user,network,url) values (1,'network1','username1'), (1,'network2','title2')
```

Comment: this code is what i somehow need to use i think but after the submit button pressed how will it post the values into your example? My brain is numb i cant even explain what i need lol

Answer (score 0):

The *trick* on SQL Server and Oracle is to use `union all`

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth' ,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth' ,5
```

I guess this would also work on  MySQL

Comment: i just figured out the form does not send the values to step2 , i need to open and close the formtag within the mysql query is there another way of doing this? eg making the php create the form with one button for the whole form?